# How to define the number of columns to show on Jquery Full Calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the week view, but instead of showing 7 columns per slide I want to show three columns, is it possible to archive this?

I failed to see any related method on the official documentation: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.2.5+ of Full Calendar has this kind of customization built in.

You just need to do something like this:

```
views: {
  agendaThreeDay: {
    type: 'agenda',
    duration: { days: 3 },
    buttonText: '3 day'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaThreeDay'
}
```

You can get more information on this from the document page [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).

Answer (score 0):

Pull the source, use this code (may need some additional change).

**src/agenda/AgendaThreeDayView.js**

```
fcViews.agendaThreeDay = AgendaThreeDayView;

function AgendaThreeDayView(a) {
    AgendaView.call(this, a);
}

AgendaThreeDayView.prototype = createObject(AgendaView.prototype);

$.extend(AgendaThreeDayView.prototype, {
    name: "agendaThreeDay",
    incrementDate: function(a, b) {
        return a.clone().stripTime().add(b, "days");
    },
    render: function(a) {
        this.intervalStart = a.clone().stripTime();
        this.intervalEnd = this.intervalStart.clone().add(3, "days");
        this.start = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalStart);
        this.end = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalEnd, -1, true);
        this.title = this.calendar.formatRange(this.start, this.end.clone().subtract(1), this.opt("titleFormat"), " — ");
        AgendaView.prototype.render.call(this, 3);
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
Remembered that you need to add the file to `lumbar.json`

Look here for how to build: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/wiki/Contributing-Code