# Full calendar 3 days agenda custom view

Tags: fullcalendar

is there a way to make a custom view based on agendaDay but restrain to 3 days, and the action on next or previous button, move 3 days on 3 days ?

the first day always reference to moment().day()

thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried defining a new view Object ? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164170/how-to-define-the-number-of-columns-to-show-on-jquery-full-calendar/26218993#26218993

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define the number of columns to show on Jquery Full Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164170/how-to-define-the-number-of-columns-to-show-on-jquery-full-calendar)

Answer (score 8):

This can now be done with something like this:

```
views: {
  agendaThreeDay: {
    type: 'agenda',
    duration: { days: 3 },
    buttonText: '3 day'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaThreeDay'
}
```

You can get more information on this from the document page on [Custom Views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).