# want to display 3 day at a time in week view of fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on jquery [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin.I did code for, by default, shows entire week view but I want to display 3 day at a time and after onclick button display next days.How can I do this?

```
enter code here
```

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

```
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full calendar 3 days agenda custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276331/full-calendar-3-days-agenda-custom-view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained rather well in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).

What you want is probably something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z0au4L8x/1/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        center: 'agendaThreeDay' // buttons for switching between views
    },
    views: {
        agendaThreeDay: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 3 },
            buttonText: '3 day'
        }
    },
    defaultView:'agendaThreeDay'
});
```